# Help with Alias

Tags: bash, alias

I frequently use:

```
find /home -iname foo* 2> /dev/null
```

The `2> /dev/null` suppresses any permissions issues and leaves legit matches.

I tried creating:

```
alias lost=find /home -iname ${1} 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 6):

Since your command has one argument, it can't be an alias.
You should define it as a function instead.

```
function lost {
    find /home -iname ${1} 2> /dev/null
}
```